# How to add context functionalities in Messenger Bot?

Tags: node.js, facebook, bots, messenger

I'm creating a simple bot and I intend to create a receipt from user messages. I've implemented the code and it takes info from the last message from the user.
I want to fetch older messages so I can show a receipt to users. How can I do that? Can I store data somewhere, like in tags or notes of messenger and update time to time? As I've read somewhere that you can't log data into some thirdparty because of Facebook privacy concerns.
How can I do that in **Node.js**?

My code is similar to this one: https://github.com/jw84/messenger-bot-tutorial

Comment: _“As I've read somewhere that you can't log data into some thirdparty because of Facebook privacy concerns”_ - you read wrong. If you are not sure what you can and can’t do, start with https://developers.facebook.com/policy

Comment: And the messages are obviously part of a conversation, and there’s an API endpoint to get messages from those. But you should probably rather cache this data on your end, because in an active, ongoing conversation between the user and your page you don’t want to waste time on additional API calls all the time.